# How to reduce margin (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a pretty minor point, but I cannot figure out how to reduce the margin above the blue bar with '136 laptops' and the buttons above it.

I've copied all the relevant CSS and HTML to [here](http://www.bootply.com/CyQpXpbHtf), which for some reason shows the leftmost dropdowns on top of each other, whereas they're fine for me. How can I target and reduce this margin?
[image]

Comment: post your code. what have you done till now?

Comment: My code is here: http://www.bootply.com/CyQpXpbHtf

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the link on your question, there doesn't appear to be any margin between the elements you talk about, but the `location` and `type` menu boxes on the left hand side are stacking rather than being inline'd, so setting :

```
.dropdown, .dropup {
    display: inline-block; /* add this */
    position: relative;
}
```

will cause both dropdowns to appear on the same row, rather than stacking underneath each other.

---

Altenatively you can *reduce* the margin to below zero but this will risk overlapping elements and is generally probably not a good idea, but you could:

```
.panel-body > p:first-of-type {
     margin-top:-5px /*move the block up by 5px */
}
```

Which would effect the first paragraph child of the panel-body class.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why they stack in Bootply because as you can see from the picture I posted, they do not stack and look fine in my original code.

Comment: They stack because the `.dropdown` are by brwoser default `bock` level elements. so they never sit next to each other.